# Perl code for Find and replace a tag value in XML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

Below is the XML I will be using:

`<a>`

`<id>ABC</id>`

`<class />`

`<gender />`

`</a>`

I want to write a Perl code which search for tag 'id' and replace the value "ABC" with "DEF".

However the nesting of above XML can change. So I want to make a generalized code that search for the tag 'id' independently of its exact position.

Till now i am able to get the logic where i can replace the value in ABC but that makes my code static of the position of tag 'id'.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Data::Dumper;
my $FileName = 'sample.xls';
my $xml_file = 'hello.xml';
$par=$ARGV[0];
my $xml = XMLin($xml_file,
    KeepRoot=>1,
    ForceArray=>1,);
$xml->{a}->[0]->{id}='DEF';
XMLout(
    $xml,
    KeepRoot =>1 ,
    NoAttr =>1,
    OutputFile => $xml_file,
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XPath is able to find nodes without needing to know the position in the tree.

```
use strictures;
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'XML');
<a>
<id>ABC</id>
<class />
<gender />
</a>
XML

for my $id ($dom->findnodes('//id[string()="ABC"]')) {
    $id->removeChildNodes;
    $id->appendText('DEF');
}

print $dom->toString
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple XML::Twig solution would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $FILE= 'id.xml';

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'id[string()="ABC"]' => sub { $_->set_text( 'DEF'); } },
                keep_spaces => 1,
              )
          ->parsefile( $FILE)
          ->print_to_file( $FILE);
```

Just for fun: an efficient XML::Twig solution is a bit more convoluted, mostly because you can't use `string()` conditions with `twig_roots`. Still, it's quite compact, and it never loads the whole file in memory.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_roots =>    { id => sub { $_->flush }, },
                twig_handlers => { 'id[string()="ABC"]' => sub { $_->set_text( 'DEF'); } },
                twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
              )
          ->parsefile_inplace( 'id.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

perl -i.bak -pe 's/abc/def/g' myfile.xml

you'll get a new file myfile.xml.bak which ha

Comment: Incomplete and therefore not a very useful answer